# What is the correct way to determine page type in WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin and only work it take effect when it is a `Page`, but not `Blog`

e.g.

```
public function init() {

  if (is_page())
     // do something..
}
```

It does not work as `is_page` is only available after `wp_query` is run [1]

So what are the suggested way to check if current page type is `Page` or `Blog`?

[1] http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/query.php#L0

Comment: what is it supposed to display? why not move it from the init() to a new function which you can then hook into wp_head? this way the page is loaded and eveything is at your disposal

Comment: @Marty, I want to hook some `filters` only when it is confirmed as `Page` type, so I am not sure if `wp_head`  or other place is too late...so I put in the `init`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use is_page() outside of wp_query if you have either of this 3 values:- page ID,page Title or slug.

If you want to check this when the page is loading you could get the id or slug for the permalink and test it using is_page.